# issue with the docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was trying the example provided in the link below for wordpress linking with mysql.

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/

I tried working without the volumes and its working fine. However, when I added volumes in the docker-compose.yml file, it started to give me the following error

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 12
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
web:
image: wordpress
links:
 - mysql
environment:
 - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
ports:
 - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
mysql:
image: mysql:5.7
environment:
 - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
 - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress

working_dir: /var/www/html
volumes:
 - wordpress/wp-content/: /home/tgandhi
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try taking out the space before `/home/tgandhi`. Also, you might need to do `./wordpress/wp-content` if that is a relative path.

Comment: Tried both the solutions provided but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First** of all, `working_dir` and `volumes` need to go into the `web` section of your compose file, not in the `mysql` section.

**Secondly**, the volume mapping is `<host path>:<container path>`.

As you specified `/var/www/html` as your working dir, the wordpress image uses `/var/www/html/wp-content` as the base directory. So you need to mount the directory on your host with static files into `/var/www/html/wp-content`. I assuming this to be `~/wordpress`.

```
web:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - mysql
  environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
  ports:
    - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
  working_dir: /var/www/html
  volumes:
    - /home/tgandhi/wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```